# How to Sign In to Your Work or School Account Using a Managed Apple ID with MDM?

Tags: ios, apple-id, mdm, apple-business

I am trying to sign in using my managed work Apple ID on an iPhone through the settings under VPN & Device Management. When I input my email address, I get "Sign-In Failed", "Your Apple ID does not support the expected services on this device. Contact your administrator to sign in".

I am the MDM administrator, but do not know what this means. I am correctly enrolled into ABM, and my domain is approved. What other steps do I need to take in order to allow such a sign in?

Answer (score 3):

When enrolling a device via Settings > General > VPN & Device Management this error happens and is reproducible. When I enroll the device in BYOD by visiting https://mycompany.jamfcloud.com/enroll it all worked fine.

If you also receive this error:

[image]

[Check n8felton's answer for the related requirements](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/440202/5472).

Our failure was because our web server was not returning the correct content type for the hosted `com.apple.remotemangement` file, which needs to return the `content-type` `application/json`, so don't overlook that in the docs!

The best way to check this is to use the Developer Tools in a web browser and check the Header Response like this:

[image]

For an Apache web server the solution is to configure the correct MIME type in either the `httpd.conf` file, in an `.htaccess` file in your `public_html` folder, or through your admin portal. In our case we are on a shared web server so don't have access to the `httpd.conf` file and the changes we applied in our cPanel portal also had no effect.

The answer was to add an entry in the `.htaccess` file.

An Apache `.htaccess` file would need the following entry:

```
AddType application/json remotemanagement
```

However our web server is running LiteSpeed so the entry is different. For a LiteSpeed server, the entry in the .htaccess file needs to be this:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

<FilesMatch "[^.]+\.remotemanagement$">
  Header set Content-Type "application/json"
  Header set Content-Encoding "UTF-8"
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your device also trying to sing in to VPN and Device management sections of iOS or do you get this error in mobile safari browsing a web site you run privately?

Comment: Yes, this is enrolling via `Settings > General > VPN & Device Management`. When I enroll the device in BYOD by visiting `https://mycompany.jamfcloud.com/enrol` it all worked fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that going to https://mycompany.jamfcloud.com/enroll is using the  profile-driven user enrollment and is different from the newer account-driven user enrollment that is being invoked when using the "Sign in to Work or School Account" screen in General > VPN & Device Management. Jamf Pro account-driven https://docs.jamf.com/10.38.0/jamf-pro/documentation/Account-Driven_User_Enrollment_for_Personally_Owned_Mobile_Devices.html vs Jamf Pro profile-driven https://docs.jamf.com/10.38.0/jamf-pro/documentation/User_Enrollment_Experience_for_Personally_Owned_Mobile_Devices.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is referred to as [account-based user enrollment](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/user-enrollment-and-mdm-dep23db2037d/1/web/1.0#dep798f25ab7) and it requires some additional configuration on your domain and MDM to work.

I highly recommend watching the Apple Developer session [Discover account-driven User Enrollment (wwdc21-10136)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10136/) The relevant section starts at about the [6:30 mark](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10136/?time=390).

Here are some of the highlights.

You will need to provide a well-known HTTP resource for your domain at the [expected discovery URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/discover_authentication_servers) e.g. `https://example.com/.well-known/com.apple.remotemanagement`. This resource will need to be available via an HTTP GET request, and the HTTP server must return the resource with a `Content-Type: application/json` header.

You can verify that your HTTP server is return the resource correctly with a `curl` command such as

```sh
curl -I https://example.com/.well-known/com.apple.remotemanagement

HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/json
```

The domain name will need to match the domain used with the Managed Apple ID (MAID), e.g. the MAID `john.appleseed@example.com` will match the above URL, but `john.appleseed@example.io` will not.

This resource will need to return a JSON document formatted like this

```
{
    "Servers": [{
        "Version": "mdm-byod",
        "BaseURL": "https://mdmserver.example.com/enroll"
    }]
}
```

The BaseURL key specifies the URL of the MDM server's enrollment endpoint. You will need to refer to your specific MDM's documentation for what this URL should be, but here are a few I was able to find as examples.

| MDM | BaseURL Example |
| --- | --- |
| [Jamf Pro](https://docs.jamf.com/10.34.0/jamf-pro/documentation/Account-Driven_User_Enrollment_for_Personally_Owned_Mobile_Devices.html) | `https://myorganiztion.org/servicediscoveryenrollment/v1/userenroll` |
| VMware Workspace One UEM | `https://ds####.awmdm.com/DeviceManagement/Enrollment/AccountDrivenUserEnroll` |

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify this is the apple business manager beta correct?

I had a similar issue with this and was pulling my hair out on it and even went through a long call with the support team on it.

I know it sounds very silly and I'm still trying to understand how it worked for me but try rebooting the device back up and signing in. I went the extra mile and wiped it through Apple Configurator (No profiles added in my case just decided to use it since I do it for the other devices I manage). But try the reboot first before backing up the device and starting from scratch. I really hope this helps you!